# Couldn't debug project about Servlet/JSP - Java on NetBean 7.1.1

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I could run but I couldn't debug my Java web project on NetBean IDE.

And the error:

```
D:\2_HOAN CHINH\1_HOC KY II\Java programming\Bai tap\MVC2_VnMart\nbproject\build-impl.xml:845: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2_HOAN CHINH\1_HOC KY II\Java programming\Bai tap\MVC2_VnMart\nbproject\build-impl.xml:851: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/Bootstrap
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.AttachingDICookie.findAttachingConnector(AttachingDICookie.java:250)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.AttachingDICookie.create(AttachingDICookie.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.JPDADebugger.attach(JPDADebugger.java:280)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAConnect$1.run(JPDAConnect.java:228)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1411)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1991)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Do you think you can post the code where this error is occurring? It's sort of hard to debug something we can't see ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/Bootstrap
```

Check your Bootstrap class. It might be on the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

According to this message:
"org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAConnect$1.run(JPDAConnect.java:228)"

This is a issue of ANT that does not run smoothly under your NetBeans.

So you may try to install another NetBeans distribution and run the project on it.